# Simple SQL query but wrong results returned

Tags: mysql

I have a simple click tracking system that consists of three tables "tracking" (which holds unique views), "views" (which holds raw views) and "products" (which holds products).

Here's how it works: each time a user clicks on a tracking link, if the hash present in the link does not exist in the database, it will be saved in the "tracking" table as an unique view and also in the "views" table as a raw view. If the hash present in the link does exist in the database, then it will be saved only in the "views" table. So basically the number of "raw views" can not be smaller than the number of "unique views" because each "unique view" also counts as a "raw view".

I wrote a query to create reports based on products, but the number of "raw views" returned is not correct.

I've also created a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e748af8/1) which I hope it will give a better overview of my problem.

Here's the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Test product');

CREATE TABLE `tracking` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `tracking` (`id`, `product_id`, `hash`, `created`) VALUES
(1, 1, '7ddf32e17a6ac5ce04a8ecbf782ca509', '2020-02-09 18:50:19'),
(2, 1, '00bb28eaf259ba0c932d67f649d90783', '2020-02-09 18:55:34');

CREATE TABLE `views` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `views` (`id`, `hash`, `created`) VALUES
(1, '7ddf32e17a6ac5ce04a8ecbf782ca509', '2020-02-09 18:46:30'),
(2, '7ddf32e17a6ac5ce04a8ecbf782ca509', '2020-02-09 18:46:30'),
(3, '7ddf32e17a6ac5ce04a8ecbf782ca509', '2020-02-09 18:46:35'),
(4, '7ddf32e17a6ac5ce04a8ecbf782ca509', '2020-02-09 18:46:42'),
(5, '00bb28eaf259ba0c932d67f649d90783', '2020-02-09 18:56:31'),
(6, '00bb28eaf259ba0c932d67f649d90783', '2020-02-09 18:57:01');
```

And here's the query I wrote so far:

```
SELECT products.name AS `param`,
SUM(IF(tracking.product_id<>24, 1, 0)) AS `uniques`,
IF(SUM(IF(tracking.product_id<>24, 1, 0))=0, 0,
            (SELECT COUNT(`hash`)
             FROM `views` WHERE tracking.hash = views.hash)) AS `views`
FROM tracking
LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = tracking.product_id
WHERE tracking.created BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-02-10 00:00:00'
GROUP BY products.name
```

As you can see I have 2 unique views and 6 raw views (4 for one hash and 2 for the other hash).

My expectation would be for the query result to be 2 uniques and 6 raw views for this given product, but instead I'm getting 2 uniques and 4 raw views. Like it's counting the views only for the first hash.

Comment: are you working on your sql fiddle? loaded up then stopped working.

Comment: Nope. I had the window opened, but I closed it now. If you remove the /1 at the end of the URL it seems like it's loading but then you get an error saying "Unable to get host connection: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!". Hopefully this will get fixed soon :)

Comment: Would you be looking more for this? (SELECT COUNT(`hash`)
FROM `views` WHERE created BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-02-10 00:00:00') AS `view in your sub query

Comment: If I make the query for a single product then it's fine, otherwise it still returns wrong numbers for the raw views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next query can solve your situation:

```
SELECT 
    products.name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT  `tracking`.`hash`) AS  `uniques`, -- count unique hashes
    COUNT(*) AS  `views` -- count total
FROM `tracking`
JOIN `views` ON `views`.hash = tracking.hash
LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = tracking.product_id
WHERE tracking.created BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-02-10 00:00:00'
GROUP BY products.name;
;
```